# Linking selection parameters in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to create a shiny app that allows me filter data of leagues. This is an example of the dataset:

```
 list <- c(2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.8, 4.12, 5.3, 6.2, 8.2)
 team <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
 time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
 league <- c("A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B")

 df <- data.frame(list, team, time, league)
```

Im plotting the data now using the following scripts:

```
#ui script
shinyUI(fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Basic widgets"),

 fluidRow(

  column(3,
       h3("Buttons"),

       selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
                   choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2), selected = 1)),

   mainPanel(
     plotOutput("distPlot")
   )
  ) 
 ))
```

And the server script:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 

list <- c(2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.8, 4.12, 5.3, 6.2, 8.2)
team <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
league <- c("A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B")

df <- data.frame(list, team, time, league)
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = list, colour = team)) + geom_line() 
 })
})
```

This show me the line of both the two leagues. But what I would like to achieve is that I can select "Choice1" and "Choice2" and the relevant datapoints are shown in the graph. Any suggestion how i can link the select choices to unique league values?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your expected output is. However, what I think you're asking is how to make the plot change given the choices in the `selectInput`?

If that's the case you need to make your plot **reactive**, by filtering the data by the given choices. See my comments in the code for further detail.

Note: I've made your app into a [single-file shiny app](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Basic widgets"),

    fluidRow(

        column(3,
                     h3("Buttons"),

                     selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
                                            choices = list("A", "B"), selected = 1, multiple = TRUE)),

        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    ) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    list <- c(2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.8, 4.12, 5.3, 6.2, 8.2)
    team <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
    time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    league <- c("A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B")

    df <- data.frame(list, team, time, league)

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 

        ## make the plot reactive depending on the input of the selectInput 'select'.
        df_plot <- df[df$league %in% input$select, ]
        ## every time you make a change to selectInput 'select', this plot will update

        ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = time, y = list, colour = team)) + 
            geom_line() 

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```